# Delphi Append packet to TBytes, validate and read

Tags: delphi, sockets, tcp, arrays, delphi-xe3

I have this [PCB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printed_circuit_board) with an [ATMEL-microcontroller](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/default.aspx) communication over TCP via [Lantronix Xport](http://www.lantronix.com/device-networking/embedded-device-servers/xport.html).  It sends status reports of some relays and sensors with an asci string, 30 bytes long, formatted like this:

```
400000000000000000414243303031303030303030303030303030303339
|                 | | |
| byte[0] = $40   | | |
                  | | |- byte[11] = $43 // 'C' Always 
                  | |--- byte[10] = $42 // 'B' Always
                  |----- byte[9]  = $41 // 'A' Always

byte[1..8] = boolean values := Bool(byte[x]);
byte[12..29] = 6 different numbers as string, 3 chars long each, range 0..999
```

I've made a simple validation of the packets for loading status:

```
procedure Load(iData: TBytes);
const vsp = 9;  //Validation String Postition
   buflen = 30;
begin
  If (Length(iData) = buflen) And (iData[0] = $40) And (iData[vsp] = $41) And (iData[vsp + 1] = $42) And (iData[vsp + 2] = $43) Then
    SetStatus(iData)  //Function for loading validated packet
  Else Begin
    DoError(1, 'Invalid packet. Length = ' + IntToStr(Length(iData)) + #13#10 +
               'iData[0]       = ' + String(ByteToHex(iData[0])) + #13#10 +
               'iData[vsp]     = ' + String(ByteToHex(iData[vsp])) + #13#10 +
               'iData[vsp + 1] = ' + String(ByteToHex(iData[vsp + 1])) + #13#10 +
               'iData[vsp + 2] = ' + String(ByteToHex(iData[vsp + 2]))
               );
  End;
End;
```

The problem is that sometimes the asci string is split up over several packets or concatenate into on packet (first number is tickcount):

```
4239483 4000  // Could be missing in case of disconnect-reconnect.
4239514 00000000000000414243303030303030303030303030303030303338400000000000000000414243
4239545 303031303030303030303030303030303339
4239576 400000000000000000414243303031303030303030303030303030303339400000000000000000414243303031303030303030303030303030303338
4239670 40000000000000000041424330303130
4239701 3030303030303030303030303339
```

In cases of disconnect-reconnect parts of the status information will be missing.

**How can I utilize TMemoryStream or Move in order to read every packet recieved without discarding any information?**

EDIT:
The SetStatus looks like this, so I would like to avoid porting the status report to a string:

```
Procedure TTractor.SetStatus(AData: TBytes);
begin
  StatusStream := AData;
  pStatus.HighSpeed             := Bool(AData[1]);
  pStatus.RevDir                := Bool(AData[2]);
  pStatus.FwdDir                := Bool(AData[3]);
  pStatus.FrontExpanded         := Bool(AData[4]);
  pStatus.RearExpanded          := Bool(AData[5]);
  pStatus.AntiSpin              := Bool(AData[6]);
  pStatus.Unknown1              := DecodePCBNumber(AData[12], AData[13], AData[14]);
  pStatus.PumpPressureVoltage   := DecodePCBNumber(AData[15], AData[16], AData[17]);
  pStatus.Unknown2              := DecodePCBNumber(AData[18], AData[19], AData[20]);
  pStatus.WheelPressureVoltage  := DecodePCBNumber(AData[21], AData[22], AData[23]);
  pStatus.OilTemperatureVoltage := DecodePCBNumber(AData[24], AData[25], AData[26]);
  pStatus.PCBTemperatureVoltage := DecodePCBNumber(AData[27], AData[28], AData[29]);
End;
```

Reading code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  If Traktor = nil Then Traktor := TTractor.Create(500);
  //...
End;

// TidConnectionIntercept
procedure TForm1.trCItcReceive(ASender: TIdConnectionIntercept; var ABuffer: TArray<System.Byte>);
Var
  tmpList: TList;
  i: Integer;
Begin
  If Traktor <> nil Then Traktor.StatusTBytes := ABuffer;
  AppendConLog(TraktorReceive, False, False, BytesToHexStr(ABuffer) );
End;

procedure TForm1.AppendConLog(LogTyp: TLogType; ShowInConsole, PlainText: Boolean; Text: String);
begin
  If ShowInConsole Or (PlainText And DebugMode) Then Begin
    MemoConsole.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime('[hh:nn:ss] ', Now) + Text);
    Text := String2Hex(AnsiString(Text));
  End;
  LogFile.Add(IntToHex(DateTimeToUNIXTimeFAST(Now()), 8) + ' ' + IntToHex(GetTickCount, 8) + ' ' +
              IntToHex(Word(ShowInConsole), 1) + IntToHex(Word(PlainText), 1) + ' ' +
              IntToHex( Ord(LogTyp), 2) + ' ' + Text);
end;

Type TTractor = class
    constructor Create(LoadInterval: Cardinal; SyncInterval: Cardinal = 25);
    //....
  public
    property StatusTBytes: TBytes read StatusStream write Load;    
  //...
End;
```

Comment: this addresses nearly the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436319/comport-readstr

Comment: That is a nice one.  However I would like to avoid porting it to a string unless I have to.

Comment: What are you using to read the TCP data? If Indy, for instance, you could just call `ReadBytes(30)` when needed and let it deal with the  packet splits/concatenations for you.

Comment: You don't have to port it to a string, just get the idea from it and work with `Byte` instead of `Char` and `TBytes` instead of `string`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, indy, TIdConnectionIntercept.OnReceive, but reading like that will not change that the Lantronix Xport splits up the packets due to bad syncing with the atmel chip.

Comment: @wittrup: An `Intercept` is meant for manipulating data (compression, encryption, etc), not for detecting when to read data. Use `IOHandler` methods instead, like `ReadBytes()`. `TIdIOHandler` has its own internal buffer to handle split/concatenated packets for you. This lets you focus on your higher level logic (read a 30-byte message) while Indy handles the lower-level details (reading in a loop until 30 bytes are available, caching unused data for subsequent reads, etc). If you show your current reading code, I can help you rewrite it to use Indy's `IOHandler` correctly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Question updated with reading code.

Comment: FWIW it doesn't add up: *"6 different numbers as string, 3 chars long each"* requires 18 bytes, you have 17 in [12..29].

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz Range [Left..Right] contains (Right-Left+1) numbers

Comment: @MBo - Yeah, quite right.

Comment: @wittrup: wbere is your actual reading code? An `Intercept.OnReceive` event does not trigger by itself, it is triggered within the context of another reading operation. For that matter, are you using `TIdTCPClient` or `TIdTCPServer` to manage the TCP connection? It makes a difference.

Comment: @RemyLebeau TIdTCPClient.  And that is the read code.  Delphi XE 3 if that makes any difference...

Comment: @wittrup: there is nothing in that code that would ever trigger the `OnReceive` event. Get rid of the `Intercept` completely, and then call ` TIdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes(30)` in a timer or worker thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Intercept.OnReceive` event does not trigger by itself, it is triggered within the context of another reading operation. There is nothing in the code you showed that performs any reading and thus would never trigger the `OnReceive` event.

An `Intercept` is meant for manipulating data (compression, encryption, etc), not for detecting when to read data.  Use `IOHandler` methods instead, like `ReadBytes()`. `TIdIOHandler` has its own internal buffer to handle split/concatenated packets for you. This lets you focus on your higher level logic (read a 30-byte message) while Indy handles the lower-level details (reading in a loop until 30 bytes are available, caching unused data for subsequent reads, etc).

Get rid of the `Intercept` completely, and then call `TIdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes()` when needed, eg:

In a timer:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPClient1Connected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ReadTimer.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPClient1Disconnected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ReadTimer.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.ReadTimerElapsed(ASender: TObject);
var
  Buffer: TIdBytes;
Begin
  try
    if IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
    begin
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(10);
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;
      if IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then Exit;
    end;
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, 30);
  except
    IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
    Exit;
  end;
  If Traktor <> nil Then Traktor.StatusTBytes := Buffer;
  AppendConLog(TraktorReceive, False, False, BytesToHexStr(Buffer) );
End;
```

Or in a worker thread:

```
type
  TDataEvent = procedure(const Data: TIdBytes) of object;

  TReadingThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FBuffer: TIdBytes;
    FClient: TIdTCPClient;
    FOnData: TDataEvent;
    procedure DoData;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AClient: TIdTCPClient; AOnData: TDataEvent); reintroduce;
  end;

constructor TReadingThread.Create(AClient: TIdTCPClient; AOnData: TDataEvent);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FClient := AClient;
  FOnData := AOnData;
end;

procedure TReadingThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    FClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes(FBuffer, 30);
    Synchronize(DoData);
  end;
end;

procedure TReadingThread.DoData;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnData) then FOnData(FBuffer);
end;
```

```
var
  ReadThread: TReadingThread = nil;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPClient1Connected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ReadThread := TReadingThread.Create(IdTCPClient1, DataAvailable);
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPClient1Disconnected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(ReadThread) then
  begin
    ReadThread.Terminate;
    ReadThread.WaitFor;
    FreeAndNil(ReadThread);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.DataAvailable(const Data: TIdBytes);
begin
  If Traktor <> nil Then Traktor.StatusTBytes := Data;
  AppendConLog(TraktorReceive, False, False, BytesToHexStr(Data) );
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add each portion of data from port to global buffer: ansistring
Check if buffer contains needed header at position 1 (otherwise remove all before header byte), and check that buffer length >= buflen. If so, treat data and remove it from buffer.

Comment: I would add a check for possible headers before treating as data to account for disconnects.